# Discord.js - Bot sending wrong message when trying to use _leave command on music bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been making a music bot using the tutorials made by the YouTube channel Plexi Development. I have copied the code, but when I do the _leave command, despite me being in the same voice channel as my bot, he says 'Sorry, but you are not in the same voice channel as me so you can't make me leave!' instead of leaving. Does anyone know why he does this?

Here is my code:

```
exports.run = (bot, message, args, ops) => {
  if(!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to get me to leave it!');
  if(!message.guild.me.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('I need to be in a voice channel to leave one, silly!');
  if(!message.guild.me.voiceChannelID !== message.member.voiceChannelID) return message.channel.send("Sorry, but you are not in the same voice channel as me so you can't make me leave!");
  message.guild.me.voiceChannel.leave();
  message.channel.send("I've left now!");
}
module.exports.config = {
    command: "leave"
}
```

For all the files I have see here: https://hastebin.com/pofivesico.js (It is all 3 of my files as one - look for the comments to see where new files start)
I am using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKDAC996nKI

Comment: In accordance with SO rules/guidelines, please include the full [Minimal, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) **in the body of your question**

Comment: My code is there. It’s a hastebin link

Comment: To re-iterate, the code itself must be present within the body of your question, not as a link, in order to conform with SO's posting guidelines. Please see the [Minimal, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page.

Comment: I've edited it to display just one of the files I have that is the most important with a link to all the files if someone needs to look at the other files. Hope this solves the problem :)

Comment: You mentioned your bot sends a message "*You need to be in the same voice channel as me*", but that string doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Can you edit to add clarity as to *exactly* which error message you're encountering?

Comment: I was just shortening down 'Sorry, but you are not in the same voice channel as me so you can't make me leave!' I'll just edit it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue likely lies here:

```
if(!message.guild.me.voiceChannelID !== message.member.voiceChannelID) return message.channel.send("Sorry, but you are not in the same voice channel as me so you can't make me leave!");
```

The [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) (`!`) in `!message.guild.me.voiceChannelID` is casting whatever value is stored in `voiceChannelID` to a `bool`. If its value is set, it will generally evaluate to `true`. I wouldn't expect that the comparison of `true` to the value of `message.member.voiceChannelID` would ever equal each other.

Remove this logical NOT to properly compare the two values.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! :)